# CQRS: Queries and business rules

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I am using CQRS, DDD and Clean architecture with NodeJs and in my queries side I need to use some business rules (calculation, here getNetRealEstateAssets()) for return some informations from my API.

I have a GetTenantsQuery and a GetTenantsHandler class :

```
export default class GetPerformancesHandler {
   async execute(query) {
     const tenants = tenantRepository.find();

     return tenants; // array of TenantQueryModel
   }   
}
```

```
class TenantQueryModel {

  constructor(){
    this.rents = [];
    this.grossAssets = xxx;
    this.liabilities = xxx;
  }

  getNetRealEstateAssets = () => {
    if (!this.grossAssets || !this.liabilities) return null;

    const round = (amount, roundLevel) => (amount / roundLevel).toFixed() * roundLevel;
    let netRealEstateAssets = this.grossAssets - this.liabilities;
    netRealEstateAssets =
      netRealEstateAssets > 10000 ? round(netRealEstateAssets, 1000) : round(netRealEstateAssets, 100);

    return netRealEstateAssets;
  };
}
```

The queries don't use the Domain layer, so where can I put this business rules ? 
(perhaps later the same in the domain layer for the commands)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One of the key tenants of CQRS is that you have separate models for queries vs updates/commands.  Your Domain objects will be separated, and have separate business rules attached to them.  The key here is, if you are using DDD, that your queries WILL have a domain layer, just not the same one as your command side.

If you aren't seeing a lot of value by having separated command and query models, then you likely don't need to use CQRS, and should normalize into a single model.  CQRS is meant to be used in scenarios where your command patterns are very different from your query patterns.  If you are repeating your code between the two models, then your system is likely not a good candidate for this pattern.

https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html

Comment: Eager Read Derivation (https://martinfowler.com/bliki/EagerReadDerivation.html) is not a good solution ?

Comment: Sure, but Eager Read requires that your data be already structured how you need it for display.  The domain logic exists on the write side of things, not on the read.  Same situation ultimately, you have a domain model that is shaping the data, but that shaped data gets written.  It's effectively a serialized cache of your Query Model domain objects.  That's why they don't need another model on the way out of the database, the model has already been applied.